# How to store value in p:commandButton?

Tags: jsf, variables, primefaces, javabeans, commandbutton

I want to store the value shown on the p:commandButton, in a variable that is in the backing bean. Here is my command button.

```
<p:commandButton value="#{rec.UTILITY_BILL_UPLOAD}" actionListener="#{pavReqAssign.DownloadFile}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" >
<p:fileDownload value="#{pavReqAssign.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

and the variable i want to store the value (i.e "#{rec.UTILITY_BILL_UPLOAD}") in, is:

```
string fileNameDL;
```

Comment: @kocko Yes, exactly that, along with the execution of "DownloadFile" function in the bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, assuming that the property `fileNameDL` is declared in the managed-bean `pavReqAssign` :

```
<p:commandButton value="#{rec.UTILITY_BILL_UPLOAD}" actionListener="#{pavReqAssign.DownloadFile}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pavReqAssign.fileNameDL}" value="#{rec.UTILITY_BILL_UPLOAD}" />
    <p:fileDownload value="#{pavReqAssign.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thank you, Omar. Works okay.